# Does installing packages using ELPA or MELPA need some additional steps for installing them manually?

Tags: package

I want to understand the different ways for installing a package, leading to readily using the package.

I compared [Emacs: How to Install Packages Using ELPA, MELPA](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html)  and [How to Install Emacs Package Manually](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html).

In the second link, if I understand correctly, the steps to install a package manually are

- (optional) byte-compilation of the package's elisp code,
- loading the package's files, and
- auto-activating the mode defined in the package, when opening files which the package is supposed to handle.

In the first link for installing a package using ELPA or MELPA, I don't find any of the three steps for installing a package manually in the first link.

1. So does the way for installing a package using ELPA or MELPA in the
   first link already do the things that are done by the three steps
   for installing a package manually in the second link? Or does the
   way for installing a package using ELPA or MELPA in the first link
   need additional steps that appear in the way for installing a
   package manually in the second link?
2. In the way for installing a package using ELPA or MELPA in the first
   link, is it necessary to add something to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using ELPA, the package is automatically byte-compiled for you, and it is also automatically activated for you.

The only thing you might want to add to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file when using ELPA is `(package-initialize)` so you can control when the installed packages get activated (in case you want to perform some setups before/after).

Comment: thanks. 1) When does `(package-initialize)` determine the installed packages get activated? 2) What about using MELPA ?

Comment: @Tim Packages distributed by MELPA are of the same format as those distributed by ELPA, so they work the same way. `(package-initialize)` runs code that operates on your local ELPA packages repository, which, in turn, will set up paths for downloaded packages and load their autoloads (thus making them available for interactive use). They won't be fully loaded though until you `require` them directly or by means of calling the autoloaded functions.

Comment: MELPA is just one of the ELPA archives, like GNU ELPA.